# Check if values exists in table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to check that multiple values exist in a table's columns, even if those values are not all in the same row?

I have this query:

```
select (select country from storage where country = 'Germany' limit 1) as country,
       (select city from storage where city = 'New York City' limit 1) as city,
       (select pet from storage where pet = 'Dog' limit 1) as pet,
       (select profession from storage where profession='owehs9843' limit 1) as profession
```

This query does what I want. If the value exists in the column then it return the searched value, otherwise it returns null.

One solution is to do an if-statement and return 1 on found and 0 if not.

However, I am not sure this is the right way to check value per column, and not per row. I want the value to exist in the column somewhere, but the rows of the key value for each column do not need to correlate.

Comment: Do you just want to determine if each of your four values exist in some row in their respective columns, and return true or false based on that? Or are you going for something else?

Comment: To put it another way; what do you want your final result to look like? Do you want either a 1 or 0, or a result set with four columns. eg; "0, 1, 1, 0" if Germany isn't in the list, NYC is, Dog is and owehs9843 is not?

Comment: i know how to do 0 or 1, but my question is if this is the best way to do it? is it the best way to check if value exists in column, for saying country israel found in table1 in column country, so the query return 1 on the country, now i want to check if dog exists in the pet column.. but dog don't have to be in the same row as the country.. so my query works, but is the the best way to do it? thanks again

Comment: You are not understanding the clarifying question. Do you want your final result to be a single boolean or an array of booleans?

Comment: array of boolean(1 or 0) but i know how to do that, i just need you to tell me if that is the right way, becuase i can do simple thing as that: select (select count(1) from storage where country='israel' limit1) as country from storage limit 1; and that same way for many columns.. is it the right way, or there is a better way? thanks alot!

Comment: I think that is perfectly fine. Nothing is particularly inefficient there, just verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this on MySql WorkBench (from Windows), the following query runs fine returning 1 when the value has been found and cero if not (for each column).

```
select if(sum(country = 'Germany') = 0, 0, 1) as country,
       if(sum(city = 'New York City') = 0, 0, 1) as city,
       if(sum(pet = 'Dog') = 0, 0, 1) as pet,
       if(sum(profession = 'owehs9843') = 0, 0, 1) as profession
from storage;
```

Comment: ya, i know that is the way, but is it the best way to do this kind of thing?